# Sha256 and URI encoding woes

Tags: racket, hmac

I am trying to port this function from javascript/node to racket

```
var crypto = require("crypto");  

function getAuthorizationTokenUsingMasterKey(verb, resourceType, resourceLink, date, masterKey) {  
    var key = new Buffer(masterKey, "base64");  

    var text = (verb || "").toLowerCase() + "\n" +   
            (resourceType || "").toLowerCase() + "\n" +   
            (resourceLink || "") + "\n" +   
            date.toLowerCase() + "\n" +   
            "" + "\n";  

    var body = new Buffer(text, "utf8");  
    var signature = crypto.createHmac("sha256", key).update(body).digest("base64");  

    var MasterToken = "master";  

    var TokenVersion = "1.0";  

    return encodeURIComponent("type=" + MasterToken + "&ver=" + TokenVersion + "&sig=" + signature);  
}
```

```

This gets a few strings, concats those creates a sha256 hash for them and at the end encodes everything for URI representation.

Here is my racket version which sadly does not yield the same results as the JS version one.
For one the last encoding into URI is missing but I also have the suspicion that the sha256 code isnt right.

```
#lang racket

(require sha)
(require threading)
(require net/base64)
(require (rename-in grommet/crypto/base64
                    (base64-encode encode)
                    (base64-decode decode)))

(define (auth-token master-key date [verb ""] [res-type ""] [res-link ""]) 

    (~>> (list verb res-type res-link date)
        (map string-downcase)
        (string-join _ "\n" #:after-last "\n")
        string->bytes/utf-8
        (hmac-sha256 (string->bytes/utf-8 master-key))
        encode
        (format "type=master&ver=1.0&sig=~a")))

(define x (auth-token "master" "Das Ist Ein Datum"))
```

**EDIT**
I tried to boil down the example so I can see what is wrong and here is what I got

```
;; racket
(encode (hmac-sha256 (decode "master")(string->bytes/utf-8 "payload"))) 
;; => pSfWnL7WUIpZwHmYB9JI891SgmMHJauJ3e0E/D5V46c="

//javascript
crypto.createHmac("sha256", "master").update("payload").digest("base64");  
//=> 'xlPQBpUTEnLGanhDb4ebS7DlFE2jE1d5mO6VjnqjhgI='
```

**Solution**

```
(define (auth-token3 master-key date [verb ""] [res-type ""] [res-link ""])
    (let* ([! string-downcase] [->bytes string->bytes/utf-8])
        (~>> (list (! verb) "\n" (! res-type) "\n" res-link "\n" (! date) "\n\n")
            string-append*
            ->bytes
            (hmac-sha256 (base64-decode (->bytes master-key)))
            base64-encode
            (format "type=master&ver=1.0&sig=~a")
            string-trim
            uri-encode)))
```

Comment: Unless your mysterious `~>>` procedure is expecting something strange, your call to `(format "type=master&ver=1.0&sig=~a")` at the end of your definition is missing anything for `format` to actually format. Where is the parameter you're passing to `format`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your boiled-down example should be

`(encode (hmac-sha256 (string->bytes/utf-8 "master")(string->bytes/utf-8 "payload")))`

not

`(encode (hmac-sha256 (decode "master")(string->bytes/utf-8 "payload")))`

The former version returns the correct result.

A possible flaw is that you `(map string-downcase)` over all the text components, whereas the JS function does not call `toLowerCase` on `resourceLink`. Try this:

```
(define (auth-token master-key date [verb ""] [res-type ""] [res-link ""])
  (let* ([! string-downcase] [->bytes string->bytes/utf-8]
         [text/list  (list (! verb) "\n" (! res-type) "\n" res-link "\n" (! date) "\n")]
         [text/bytes (->bytes (string-append* text/list))]
         [signature  (encode (hmac-sha256 (->bytes master-key) text/bytes))])
    (string-append "type=master&ver=1.0&sig=" signature)))
```

The JS version also ends by calling `encodeURIComponent`. I don't know what that does but there doesn't seem to be any equivalent in your code

Comment: There are even a few more bugs in my initial code. A) there is 2 "\n" at the end. This slipped my view when first converting [who the @!* writes that kind of code? JS <sigh>]

Comment: B) I had to decode the master-key before running hmac. `(hmac-sha256 (base64-decode (string->bytes/utf-8 master-key)))` you sure your code creates the same result as the JS code?

Comment: I like the name shortening of `(let* ([! string-downcase] [->bytes string->bytes/utf-8] ...` is that an idiomatic use within Racket?

Comment: @robkuz Positive. Try running my version of the example. You'll get "xlPQBpUTEnLGanhDb4ebS7DlFE2jE1d5mO6VjnqjhgI=". As to whether making local abbreviations is idiomatic: I've seen others do the same, and no one's criticized me for it yet :). All Schemes tend toward the verbose when it comes to identifiers, so you'd go nuts if you never abbreviated the ones you use repeatedly.

Comment: hmm - the js code returns "type%3Dmaster%26ver%3D1.0%26sig%3DrnLiG7CeHRCcBOMcG0GQ7EUwpAEvsQ3UplwwkqxpaD0%3D" I have added my solution above. Thx for the help